# Java isn't getting files in a directory

Tags: java, file, directory

```
    System.out.println("READ");

    String currentWorldName = "RANDOM";
    String propertiesFileDirectory = propertiesFolder + currentWorldName + "/props.properties";
    String entitiesFolderDirectory = propertiesFolder + currentWorldName + "/Entities";

    try 
    {
        properties.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesFileDirectory));
    } 

    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        //Since it doesn't exist either it was deleted by the user or hasn't been created yet.
        createNewPropertiesFile();
    } 

    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        outputToLog("IOException when loading properties file for the world: '" + currentWorldName + "'.\n" + e.getStackTrace().toString());
    }

    //getting values from properties

    //Now to read each properties file in Entities
    File entitiesFolder = new File(entitiesFolderDirectory);

    try 
    {
        List<String> entitiesDirectoryContents = Arrays.asList(entitiesFolder.list());

        //Read each file in the entities directory and load it into memory.
        for (String entityPropertiesFileName : entitiesDirectoryContents)
        {
            if (propertiesBelongsToEntityCH(entityPropertiesFileName))
            {
                                 //Get properties one way
            }

            else //The properties file we're working does not belong to CH.
            {
                //Get properties from the same file a different way
            }
        }
               //This should never be hit since we have the file to read.
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        outputToLog("FileNotFoundException when loading entity properties file." + e.getMessage().toString());
    } 

    //I don't know when/if this would be hit. It hasn't happened.
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        outputToLog("IOException when loading entity properties file." + e.getMessage().toString());
    }

    catch (NullPointerException e)
     {
          entitiesFolder.mkdirs();
     }
```

This HAS been working, I swear. It just started doing this.
Java keeps claiming that the "entitiesFolder" directory doesn't exist (I check with entitiesFolder.exists()). I have a solution for when that happens as you can see, because while my program is running it definitely can happen. Well it still claims that the folder doesn't exist, over and over.

I'm absolutely positive that it's the right directory because I print the "entitiesFolderDirectory" out to the console. It's correct. I can also be looking at the files inside of that folder and when mkdirs() runs it just deletes them all.

Java bug? This has completely broken my program.

Comment: without the actual path you are attempting to access this is, effectively, 'how long is a piece of string?'

Comment: have you tried prinitnig `entitiesFolder.getAbsolutePath()`, and not the relative path - to check if it is indeed looking for the path you think it does?

Comment: I don't see you going in loops to check that! Moreover, is this a multithreaded application? are there any threads that would wanna delete the folder?

Comment: Argh. The loop is looping through each file in the directory. I never make it to the loop. No the folder is never deleted by the program. And getAbsolutePath is returning the correct path...

Comment: probably wild, but do you have any anti-virus running? may be it blocks something

Comment: I do not have an antivirus...I'm going to post more code. Maybe that will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write it without throwing a NullPointerException.

```
File entitiesFolder = new File(entitiesFolderDirectory);
entitiesFolder.mkdirs();
for (String entityPropertiesFileName : entitiesFolder.list()) {
     //Do stuff
}
```

This will always work unless the folder could not be created.

Comment: That works...It'll say that the folder exists after doing that but it also deletes all of the files that are in it. If I take out the mkdirs(), leave the folder there, and restart the program, it claims the folder doesn't exist again.

Comment: mkdirs doesn't delete files.  It only creates an empty one if its not here.  If there are no files in it after this loop, there were no files before this loop.

Comment: That's the problem! It says the folder is not there, but it is, and it contains files. Apparently it is the right directory because if I myself delete the folder, it is restored. But also if I leave it there, with files in it, the files disappear after mkdirs().

Comment: In that case, some other part of your program is deleting the files. I would breakpoint the first line above in your debugger and check the files are still there.

Comment: Aha! Files AND the folder are gone before mkdirs()! It was a method that clears the folder that "Entities" is in running when it wasn't supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem with this code? only one curly braces i found is missing else it is working fine.

This will create a dir test in c drive if does not exist else it will list the files in test dir over n over again

```
String entitiesFolderDirectory = "C:\\test";
        File entitiesFolder = new File(entitiesFolderDirectory);

        try 
        {
            List<String> entitiesDirectoryContents = Arrays.asList(entitiesFolder.list());

            for (String entityPropertiesFileName : entitiesDirectoryContents)
            {
                System.out.println(entityPropertiesFileName);
            }

        }catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            System.out.println("creating new folder");
            entitiesFolder.mkdirs();
        }
```